# Mock theta function

Tags: integer-partitions, hypergeometric-function

I am unable to find a formal definition of the order of the mock theta function. Can you explain briefly, what is the order of the mock theta function?

Answer (score 2):

There is a formal definition. But Ramanujan did not define it clearly. His notion of order later turned out to correspond to the conductor of the Nebentypus character of the weight  $1⁄2$ harmonic Maass forms which admit Ramanujan's mock theta functions as their holomorphic projections. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_modular_form) for definitions.

Comment: Everybody knows that.

Comment: If not, wikipedia is helping out.